# Arduino Printing Formatting- How to print horizontally in a loop

Tags: arduino

I'm struggling with formatting my Serial.print statements. I am really new to arduino so I'm sorry if it's a really basic question and answer. I just can't seem to visualize it.

I have three variables that I want to print: ValveNumber, Flow per minute, and Flow per hour. These variables are arrays that contain 5 values. I have calculated them using loops.

I want them in the following format:

```
 Valve Number    Flow per minute    Flow per hour
     1                 3                  90
     2                 3                  90
     ...........................................
     5                 5                  120
```

What I have tried:

```
for(j=0;j<5;j+=1){
  Serial.print(flowmeternumber[j]); Serial.print(perminute[j]); 
  Serial.print(cumulative[j]);
   Serial.print("\t");
 }
```

The output is a mess so I won't even bother printing it on here.

Simply put, how can I print these vertically? I thought tab might work, but clearly it doesn't. Sorry for my probably way too simple question.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(j=0;j<5;j+=1){
  Serial.print(flowmeternumber[j] + "\t");
  Serial.print(perminute[j] + "\t"); 
  Serial.println(cumulative[j]);
}
```

Adding `+ "\t"` puts a tab in between the values.

`Serial.println()` is almost the same as `Serial.print()` except it moves to the next line after printing the data. (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Println)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I am trying it but something else has gone wrong (printing  only ???'s in the monitor), once fixed I will see if this solution works.

Comment: This seems to be corrupting my data. I do not know enough about arduino unfortunately to correct this.

Comment: Do you have a `Serial.begin(9600);` line in your setup function, and is the serial monitor set to the same baud rate (9600)?

Comment: Yeah that was the first thing I checked.

Comment: Put `Serial.println("Hello world");` in your setup/loop function (doesn't matter) and look for it in the serial monitor to confirm it's the data, not the Serial (try commenting out all other print commands if you can't find "Hello world" in the monitor).